# GTOPO30 elevation value are wrong in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I downloaded GTOPO30 DEM archives from USGS(earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), and I just simply drag the file into QGIS, but somehow I find the elevation isn't the same with the actual scenery.
I want to draw the terrain profile but the value isn't correct.
I open the properties→ Metadata in QGIS and the maximum value is different from the official document.

Example: GTOPO30 w180 n90
[image]

The official specification is attached.
The maximum value of this dem should be 6098, but at Qgis the Max is 4659.

Could anyone help me to deal with this error?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stats were calculated [approximately](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2014-August/039940.html). There's a few ways to fix. Easiest way is to unset existing stats with `gdal_edit` and then recompute with `gdalinfo`:

```
gdal_edit -unsetstats gt30w180n90.tif

gdalinfo -stats gt30w180n90.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gt30w180n90.tif
       gt30w180n90.tif.aux.xml
Size is 4800, 6000
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
<snip>
Band 1 Block=4800x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=6098.000, Mean=448.899, StdDev=482.694
  NoData Value=-9999
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=6098
    STATISTICS_MEAN=448.89852079342
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=482.69366038176
```

Assuming you are using QGIS on Windows, installed from [download.qgis.org](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html). Open your Start Menu -> QGIS folder -> OSGeo4W Shell:

[[image: Start Menu]]

Then simply type:

```
gdal_edit -unsetstats [full path to]\gt30w180n90.tif
```

e.g.

```
gdal_edit -unsetstats C:\Temp\gt30w180n90.tif
```

Then

```
gdalinfo -stats [full path to]\gt30w180n90.tif
```

Comment: Hello, Luke
I really appreciate your reply, but in fact, I am not familiar with Qgis.
Is the gdal_edit you mentioned a plugin? Could you tell me how to use it or give me some suggestions?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh!!!!!! It really works, thank you so much!!!!!!!
That's quiet helpful~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~